# How to ignore a warning inside a test using pytest?

Tags: python, testing, warnings, decorator, pytest

I am trying to test a function that uses `DatetimeFields`. The function I want to test is the following:

```
def get_pledge_frequency(last_week_pledges):
    """Returns two lists:
    pledge_frequency: containing the number of pledges per day of the last week
    weekdays: containing a letter that represents the day
    It assumes that last_week_pledges are pledges made within the last week.
    """
    pledge_frequency = []
    weekdays = []

    if last_week_pledges:
        last_7_days = [timezone.now() - timedelta(days=i) for i in range(7)]
        last_7_days.reverse()
        day_names = 'MTWTFSS'

        for day in last_7_days:
            pledge_frequency.append(
                last_week_pledges.filter(timestamp__date=day).count())
            weekdays.append(day_names[day.weekday()])

    return pledge_frequency, weekdays
```

I am using `pytest` for testing, so the test that I have implemented is the following:

```
pledge_frequency_ids = ['no_pledges', 'one_pledge_today',
                        'one_pledge_not_today', 'two_pledges_same_day',
                        'two_pledges_not_same_day', 'multiple_pledges_a',
                        'multiple_pledges_b']

pledge_data = [
    ('2018-03-30', [], ([], [])),
    ('2018-03-30', ['2018-03-30'], ([0] * 6 + [1], 'SSMTWTF')),
    ('2018-03-30', ['2018-03-27'], ([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 'SSMTWTF')),
    ('2018-03-31', ['2018-03-29', '2018-03-29'], ([0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], 'SMTWTFS')),
    ('2018-03-28', ['2018-03-26', '2018-03-28'], ([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], 'TFSSMTW')),
    ('2018-04-01', ['2018-03-26', '2018-03-26', '2018-03-27', '2018-03-28'], ([2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'MTWTFSS',)),
    ('2018-03-29', ['2018-03-25', '2018-03-26', '2018-03-27', '2018-03-28'], ([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], 'FSSMTWT'))]

@pytest.mark.parametrize('today, pledge_information, pledge_frequency',
                         pledge_data, ids=pledge_frequency_ids)
@pytest.mark.django_db
@mock.patch('django.utils.timezone.now')
@mock.patch('pledges.models.Pledge')
def test_get_pledge_frequency(_, mock_now, social_user, today,
                              pledge_information, pledge_frequency):
    """Tests to verify correctness of get_pledge_frequency() function.
    Covering the following cases:
    * No pledges
    * One pledge today
    * One pledge not today
    * Two pledges the same day
    * Two pledges not the same day
    * Multiple pledges particular case 0
    * Multiple pledges particular case 1"""
    mock_now.return_value = timezone.datetime.strptime(today, '%Y-%m-%d')
    for pledge_info in pledge_information:
        pledge = Pledge()
        pledge.user = social_user
        pledge.save()
        pledge.timestamp = timezone.datetime.strptime(pledge_info, '%Y-%m-%d')
        pledge.save()

    last_week_pledges = Pledge.objects.all()
    expected_frequency, expected_weekdays = pledge_frequency
    expected_weekdays = list(expected_weekdays)
    actual_frequency, actual_weekdays = get_pledge_frequency(last_week_pledges)

    assert expected_frequency == actual_frequency
    assert expected_weekdays == actual_weekdays
```

The tests passes, but the problem is that I am getting the following warning:

> RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField Pledge.timestamp received a naive datetime (2018-03-29 00:00:00) while time zone support is active.

Actually, I get several `RuntimeWarning` which notify the use of a naive datetime while time zone support is active.

How can I disable warnings just for this test? I found that using `@pytest.mark.filterwarnings` might be useful, and I have added the tag as this: `@pytest.mark.filterwarnings('ignore:RuntimeWarning')`. However, that didn't work, and after running the test I still have those warnings.

Does the order of where I put the decorator matters? I have tried several combinations, but it does't work yet.

In the documentation I found that I can add `addopts = -p no:warnings` to my `pytest.ini` file, but I don't want to follow this approach in case I get another test generating this warning.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed question (esp. the answer! It actually helped and I upvoted that)! However, I'm not sure that all your implementation details and test suite are relevant for this question to be answered (they probably could be omitted).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

According to [pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html), `@pytest.mark.filterwarnings` actually is the right approach, the problem was that the parameter that I was passing was not correct. This issue was solved by:

```
@pytest.mark.filterwarnings('ignore::RuntimeWarning') # notice the ::
```

so the test works as follows:

```
pledge_frequency_ids = ['no_pledges', 'one_pledge_today',
                        'one_pledge_not_today', 'two_pledges_same_day',
                        'two_pledges_not_same_day', 'multiple_pledges_a',
                        'multiple_pledges_b']

pledge_data = [
    ('2018-03-30', [], ([], [])),
    ('2018-03-30', ['2018-03-30'], ([0] * 6 + [1], 'SSMTWTF')),
    ('2018-03-30', ['2018-03-27'], ([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 'SSMTWTF')),
    ('2018-03-31', ['2018-03-29', '2018-03-29'], ([0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], 'SMTWTFS')),
    ('2018-03-28', ['2018-03-26', '2018-03-28'], ([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1], 'TFSSMTW')),
    ('2018-04-01', ['2018-03-26', '2018-03-26', '2018-03-27', '2018-03-28'], ([2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'MTWTFSS',)),
    ('2018-03-29', ['2018-03-25', '2018-03-26', '2018-03-27', '2018-03-28'], ([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], 'FSSMTWT'))]

@pytest.mark.parametrize('today, pledge_information, pledge_frequency',
                         pledge_data, ids=pledge_frequency_ids)
@pytest.mark.filterwarnings('ignore::RuntimeWarning')
@pytest.mark.django_db
@mock.patch('django.utils.timezone.now')
@mock.patch('pledges.models.Pledge')
def test_get_pledge_frequency(_, mock_now, social_user, today,
                              pledge_information, pledge_frequency):
    """Tests to verify correctness of get_pledge_frequency() function.
    Covering the following cases:
    * No pledges
    * One pledge today
    * One pledge not today
    * Two pledges the same day
    * Two pledges not the same day
    * Multiple pledges particular case 0
    * Multiple pledges particular case 1"""
    mock_now.return_value = timezone.datetime.strptime(today, '%Y-%m-%d')
    for pledge_info in pledge_information:
        pledge = Pledge()
        pledge.user = social_user
        pledge.save()
        pledge.timestamp = timezone.datetime.strptime(pledge_info, '%Y-%m-%d')
        pledge.save()

    last_week_pledges = Pledge.objects.all()
    expected_frequency, expected_weekdays = pledge_frequency
    expected_weekdays = list(expected_weekdays)
    actual_frequency, actual_weekdays = get_pledge_frequency(last_week_pledges)

    assert expected_frequency == actual_frequency
    assert expected_weekdays == actual_weekdays
```